# How to restrict users to enter the date manually in the date field and user can enter date only in the given date range

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, momentjs

I am working on a vueJs application in which I want to restrict user to manually enter the date out of range in the type=date field on the HTML page. I want to make that user can enter a date only in the given date range.

```js
document
          .getElementsByName("col_date")[0]
          .setAttribute("min", moment().subtract(10,'day').format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
```

[image: Date picker]

Comment: You seem to be aware of the `min` and `max` attributes, which controls the valid date range for the `input`. What is the problem?

Comment: the problem is, in the calendar, it is working fine, but when we manually type date which is restricted, now this is accepting I don't want to take those dates in manually.

Comment: That looks like a custom date input. The solution is then based on the implementation details, which is not shown in the question.